# Code maintenance: Is it better to develop in English or my mother tongue?

Tags: maintenance, languages, development

Suppose I develop an application for a given company of my own country. Is is better to code in English or with the language of my country ? I mean, if it is better to comment in French and name the variables and functions, classes in French ...

I ask this question in terms of code maintenance in the future.

Comment: If you like job security and want to make outsourcing harder: your native tongue, or even better, your local dialect. ;-)

Comment: @PieterB what you say is far from being funny, I highly appreciate your point of view giving my computer science background.

Comment: guys, the problems start when someone codes in English without having a clue about English.

Comment: I prefer English on a general basis, but there's also the issue that not all programming languages/tools like Norwegian letters like `æ`/`ø`/`å` - and those occur frequently within our language.

Comment: @zenzelezz during 4 years you did not ask or answer a question :)

Comment: @Begueradj I'm not sure entirely what difference that makes in this case; but yes - I do mostly read threads on this site :)

Comment: @MikeNakis: A firm grasp of English is usually considered as essential as a firm grasp of the programming language -- for exactly this reason. Most available documentation, *as well as help sources on the 'net*, are English. I shudder every time I see code posted on SO that has comments, or worse, *identifiers* in {native}...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'd recommend English.

Our own, Dutch speaking company bought out a French company. Having to deal with code that's written in French isn't much fun for non native speakers. And that's for people who understand some French. Our Irish/Indian colleagues wouldn't understand a word of it.

Comment: Mentioning the fact colleagues that would review and maintain  may be of different nationalities is the most convincing part for me. Thank you

Comment: Are you sure that you prefer english created by a native french speaker?

Comment: @JensSchauder: I've seen truly dismal comments and documentation written by a native *English* speaker...

Comment: I'd argue that as a programmer you should know English. In fact, some of our French colleagues have started an English course...

Comment: Just refuse dealing with it. Knowing French is an extra skill that doesn't match your job description.

Answer (score 8):

The answer, in my experience is, short and consistently: English!

When you develop for yourself, there's really nothing holding you back to comment or name things in your native language (although you shouldn't!), but code that you write for a company:

1. Doesn't belong to you
2. Might be maintained by anyone in the future

To allow yourself and others the best possibility to quickly get up to speed with a growing code base, you'd do well to make it a habit to write variable, class and method names as well as comments in English.

It is, after all, the convention and common ground that we all share (including this site!) so we can more easily understand and learn from one another. There is, in my opinion, no room for (well-meant) chauvinism or laziness in this.

I don't use these words lightly and certainly by no means imply, that you in your case would choose to use your native language to write comments because of such, but I have seen blatant displays of both in production environments, with loss of productivity as a result, having myself knowledge of *very* costly projects that have gone south because of the inability to translate the comments and method names.

For the record, I'm not a native English speaker either.

Comment: Documentation is the place for multiple language support, not code.  Even in the exceptional situation in which other languages are allowed, your next job will expect English.  Better get used to it.

Comment: @Neil: Ah... be careful with that comment. Code *needs* to be aware of language support issues, a.k.a. locales / Unicode. Too many lines of code have been written *assuming* that all text can be written in ASCII-7...

Comment: @DevSolar I was sort of playing devil's advocate.  My point was, I don't think it is ever a good idea, though should it be allowed, better not to anyway.

Comment: @Neil: Oh, I see where I misunderstood you there. You meant comments and identifiers *in* the code, I read it as also implying "don't worry about [NLS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalization_and_localization) in the code either".

Comment: @DevSolar No, certainly l18n is critical in most modern applications.